# How to use laptop as a monitor for my desktop?

Tags: laptop, display

I have to use laptop for quite a few months now, because my desktop monitor is being repaired! I need to use my laptop as a screen for my desktop PC. How can that be done? Is that Possible?

Answer (score 2):

In my knowledge this is not possible as the only ports on a laptop are outputs not inputs.. You might be able to remotely control your desktop from your laptop (using various methods) however if they have not been setup prior to you not having a monitor on your desktop then chances are they are disabled/not installed.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but only if you modify the hardware. You don't want to go down that route unless you are computer hardware specialist/enthusiast. As CharlesH correctly stated, video ports on the laptop are output-only. You would need to disassemble the laptop and modify the connection to the screen to use it as input (VGA most likely). This would require some work and would include additional costs for connectors, wires and probably interface/controller board.

Additional reading:

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Convert-a-Laptop-LCD-into-an-External-Monit/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run software on your desktop, the answers from @CharlesH and @smc are the bottom line, there is not a simple way to do it.  However, if you just need to access files on the desktop, you can do that.  There are inexpensive adapters that match your hard disk interface and convert the drive to an external USB drive (they also sell inexpensive external boxes that convert a drive to an external USB drive).  It is straightforward to remove the hard disk from the desktop and put it back.  Make sure you get the right type of adapter or cabinet for the HDD interface (IDE ribbon cable or SATA connector).

Another alternative that would allow you to use the desktop would be to use a TV as a monitor.  Most recent TVs can be connected to a computer via one or more common connections like HDMI or VGA.  All you need is a cable.  You can continue to use it as a TV by selecting which input to use.