# use Dell laptop (ubuntu / windows 10) as second extended monitor for mac book pro using HDMI cable

Tags: ubuntu, mac, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a MacBook Pro and Dell Vostro with Windows 10 and Ubuntu installed.

Is there any way so I can use Dell Vostro laptop as extended monitor for MacBook pro using HDMI cable.

I'm scared if I put HDMI in both the port of MacBook and dell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use laptop as a monitor for my desktop?](https://superuser.com/questions/810729/how-to-use-laptop-as-a-monitor-for-my-desktop)

Answer (score 1):

The HDMI ports on laptops are only output. And for your purpose you need device with HDMI input. So the answer is no, not with serious hardware intervention